# In Apache Spark, where is "SPARK_HOME/launcher/target/scala-2.13" and how can I use it?

Tags: apache-spark, scala-2.13, spark-launcher

When I launch a Spark program in local-cluster mode, I got the following error:

```
17:45:33.930 [ExecutorRunner for app-20231004174533-0000/0] ERROR org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.ExecutorRunner - Error running executor
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find any build directories.
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.CommandBuilderUtils.checkState(CommandBuilderUtils.java:228) ~[spark-launcher_2.13-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.AbstractCommandBuilder.getScalaVersion(AbstractCommandBuilder.java:241) ~[spark-launcher_2.13-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.AbstractCommandBuilder.buildClassPath(AbstractCommandBuilder.java:195) ~[spark-launcher_2.13-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.AbstractCommandBuilder.buildJavaCommand(AbstractCommandBuilder.java:118) ~[spark-launcher_2.13-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.WorkerCommandBuilder.buildCommand(WorkerCommandBuilder.scala:39) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.WorkerCommandBuilder.buildCommand(WorkerCommandBuilder.scala:45) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.CommandUtils$.buildCommandSeq(CommandUtils.scala:63) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.CommandUtils$.buildProcessBuilder(CommandUtils.scala:51) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.ExecutorRunner.org$apache$spark$deploy$worker$ExecutorRunner$$fetchAndRunExecutor(ExecutorRunner.scala:160) [spark-core_2.13-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.ExecutorRunner$$anon$1.run(ExecutorRunner.scala:80) [spark-core_2.13-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
```

Analyzing source code of Spark leads to the following code snippets that causes the error:

(the following are part of Spark 3.5.0 source code: AbstractCommandBuilder.scala, line 227)

```
  String getScalaVersion() {
    String scala = getenv("SPARK_SCALA_VERSION");
    if (scala != null) {
      return scala;
    }
    String sparkHome = getSparkHome();
    File scala213 = new File(sparkHome, "launcher/target/scala-2.13");
    checkState(scala213.isDirectory(), "Cannot find any build directories.");
    return "2.13";
    // ...
  }
```

The intention of this function is to ensure the existence of "SPARK_HOME/launcher/target/scala-2.13" to ensure that the deployed Spark is compiled using the same Scala version. Unfortunately, this directory only exists on Spark project, the binary version of Spark doesn't have it:

[image]

Should this function be improved to be compatible with both distributions?

**UPDATE 1:** Thanks a lot for Anish's suggestion that Spark distribution doesn't contain Scala binary. But in fact they do:

[image]

This could be a more reliable evidence to determine Scala version, but at this moment, it wasn't used.

Answer (score 1):

The [Spark code at `org.apache.spark.launcher.AbstractCommandBuilder#getScalaVersion()`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/launcher/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/launcher/AbstractCommandBuilder.java#L226-L234) commes from [commit 2da6d1a](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/2da6d1a8731431d03e8ffce2141d74241f0410dc) and [PR 43125](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/43125), with [PR SPARK-32434](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-32434) before that.

That seems pretty much hard-coded, which means before launching your Spark application, you need to set the `SPARK_SCALA_VERSION` environment variable to the Scala version you are using. That should bypass the directory check that is failing in `getScalaVersion()`.

Comment: I'm sorry this is question for Apache Spark, not Scala, the code snippet in my question is Spark source code, not mine

Comment: @tribbloid OK, got it. I have rewritten the answer accordingly.

Comment: Agreed it is hardcoded, my question is if it has room for improvements

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you did but I didn't face any issue while running spark.

To be precise, you have to select **Apache Spark Binary** which contains scala libraries and that comes with **spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3-scala2.13.tgz** file.

**Note:** I don't have scala installed.

[image]

Step - by - Step process on how it was working on my local.

1. Go to https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html :

   - Choose a Spark release: **3.5.0 (Sep 13 2023)**
   - Choose a package type: **Pre-built for Apache Hadoop 3.3 and later (Scala 2.13)** from the dropdown.
2. Click on Download Spark: [spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3-scala2.13.tgz](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/spark/spark-3.5.0/spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3-scala2.13.tgz)
3. After downloading, extract it on your local and it will show contents like this given below

[image]

4. Now, open the terminal from `/bin` folder.
5. Execute the command `./spark-shell --master local` to run cluster mode locally. It will work

Screenshot:

[image]

To verify whether or not it's running in local mode, enter `sc.isLocal` in scala terminal as shown in the screenshot.

**Note:** Spark 3.5.0 binary is pre-packaged with Scala libraries. So, it shouldn't throw that error.

Go the `/jars` directory and you have all of your scala libraries there.

[image]

That's all.

Comment: spark-shell by default bypass AbstractCommandBuilder, which is why it won't trigger this error, let me see if there is an argument that can trigger it ...

Comment: @tribbloid Can you tell me the command which you have executed earlier to get this error? I will try to reproduce the same.

Comment: @tribbloid Have you downloaded the spark version which contains the scala library in your local? I just want to confirm.

Comment: @tribbloid Just check one more time. `spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3-scala2.13.tgz`

Comment: @tribbloid I guess you are running worker in cluster mode and trying to connect to the worker with the master. Correct?

Comment: @tribbloid If yes, then it working for me still. I'm not facing any issue.

Comment: @tribbloid The regular version of Spark doesn't have Scala in it. You have to install install scala for that before you can run the regular version and set `SPARK_SCALA_VERSION`.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, made some update according to your comment

Comment: @tribbloid Can you tell the command that you are using to run?